# Run a salt state from one salt minion on another minion

Tags: salt-stack

I want to run the following salt state from one minion onto another minion

```
restart_mysql_on_other_nodes:
  cmd.run:
    - name: service mysql restart
```

Is this possible? If yes, How do I do it?

I don't want to run the salt directly from master as there are some dependencies on the minion, post which the above salt must run.

Comment: You should run an [orchestration](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/orchestrate/orchestrate_runner.html) on the master.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run any cmd from one server to another it will be done via **SSH** but since you want to run salt-state it is not possible.

As you said you have dependencies on one minion post which you want to trigger salt-state to another server, that will be achieved using salt [orchestration](https://%5Bhttps://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/orchestrate/orchestrate_runner.html)

The most common use case of salt orchestration is when we want to restart any webserver of services in different VMs we can use it.

Ex:

```html
Run_stop_ser1:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: azrlinvm1
    - sls:
      - lin.vm.service1stop

Run_stop_ser2:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: azrlinvm2
    - sls: 
      - lin.vm.service2stop
    - require:
      - Run_stop_ser1

Run_pkgupdate:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: 'azrlinvm*'
    - sls: 
      - state.containing.pkgupdate
      - state.containing.toolsinstallation
      - some.other.useful.state
    - require:
      - Run_stop_ser2

Run_start_ser2:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: azrlinvm2
    - sls: 
      - lin.vm.service2start
    - require:
      - Run_pkgupdate

Run_start_ser1:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: azrlinvm1
    - sls: 
      - lin.vm.service1start
    - require:
      - Run_start_ser2
```